# C#: Add a new check without affecting existing checks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hope I can explain my scenario the best I can.

I have code that when the "Load" button is clicked, all file names (if any) located in a predefined network directory path, are loaded to a text-area.

Currently there can be .txt, .xml files.

Contents could look like:

```
first_file_found.xml
second_file_found.xml
third_file_found.txt
```

Also, in the code there is another function "isCoValid" that performs an additional validation of the contents of these files, based on return value (true/false) of this function, the "Process" button is enabled:

```
if (IsFlatFile(fileName) || IsXMLFile(fileName)) 
{
    if (isCoValid(fileName))
    {
        btnProcess.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnProcess.Enabled = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now I have to add a .csv file type, but this file does not required to perform the isCoValid function.

The text-area contents now look like:

```
first_file_found.xml
second_file_found.xml
third_file_found.txt
fourht_file_found.csv
```

My request for help is to ask how can the check to find out if there is a CSV file can be done, and also controlling the enabling of the "Process" button, but still respect the existing check for .txt, and .xml and the validation of contents?

I might have xml and text files, that aren't valid, but I still need to be able to process the .csv. file.

I did change it like this:

```
if (IsFlatFile(fileName) || IsXMLFile(fileName)) 
{
    if (isCoValid(fileName))
    {
        btnProcess.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnProcess.Enabled = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (IsCSVFile(fileName))
{
    btnProcess.Enabled = true;
}
```

But I am sure this is not correct and I would like to ask for some help if possible.

I hope I explained my problem with some clarity and straightforwardness,  if not, please let me know and I can try to provide more information.

Thank you,
Erasmo

**Additional Code Requested**

```
public bool IsFlatFile(string FileName)
    bool ReturnValue = false;

    if (FileName.ToUpper().Right(4) == ".TXT")         
    {
        if ((FileName.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper() == "MN") ||
            (FileName.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper() == "CH"))

        {
            ReturnValue = true;
        }
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}

public bool IsXMLFile(string FileName)
    bool ReturnValue = false;

    if (FileName.ToUpper().Right(4) == ".XML")         
    {
        if ((FileName.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper() == "TR") ||
            (FileName.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper() == "SK"))

        {
            ReturnValue = true;
        }
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}

protected bool isCoValid(string fName)
{
    bool retCode = false;
    Parameters parms;
    var reader = new AppSettingsReader();
    Application app = new Application();
    Package package = null;

    try
    {
        package = app.LoadPackage(packagePath + "ValidateContents.dtsx", null);
        parms = package.Parameters;
        parms["ID"].Value = "";
        parms["ImportFileName"].Value = fName;
        parms["UserID"].Value = userName;
        
        DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
        if (results == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)
            {
                retCode = false;
                resultText = resultText + "DTSX Package Execution results: " + local_DtsError.Description.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resultText = resultText + "Successful Process Completion." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            string sqlStr = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Validation WHERE Type = 'VALCO' AND CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)";
            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = GetDataSet(sqlStr);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (row["Status"].ToString() == "Valid")
                    {
                        retCode = true;
                        resultText = "Output: Valid" + Environment.NewLine + "Press the 'Process' button to proceed.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        retCode = false;
                        resultText = "Output: " + row["Status"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Validation Fail: " + row["Error"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resultText = "Unable to read Validation Table for this file.";
                retCode = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return retCode;
}
```

Comment: We need to see IsFlatFile(), IsXMLFile() and isCoValid() code.

Comment: why `if (IsCSVFile(fileName)){ btnProcess.Enabled = true;}` is not correct? that mean if file is CSV the process button is always true. do you ask about factorisation?

Comment: CSV file names must start with what letters?

Comment: There is no check needed for the starting of the csv file.

Comment: Do you have package.Execute() source code?

Comment: There is a package but I don’t have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like so:

```cs
if (IsFlatFile(fileName) || IsXMLFile(fileName) || IsCSVFile(fileName))
{
    btnProcess.Enabled = isCoValid(fileName);
                
    if (!btnProcess.Enabled) break;
}

public static bool IsCSVFile(string FileName) =>
    Path.GetExtension(FileName).Equals(".csv", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

when you write your own IsCSVFile() method and update isCoValid() method to fit your needs.

Sorry, but I can't guess what happens inside classes that are used in isCoValid() method.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate your effort to help.